# Overview, multiple rasters in map canvas

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins

I work with multiple rasters and merging them into a VRT isn't an option. Is there a way to get info on what raster layer I'm looking at as a "mouse over" event within map canvas?

I'm on version 2.18 and 3.x as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And after some research I found the plugin [Value Tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/valuetool/), that work's similar to Identify Tool on click, but not by mouse over though. User will need to test it to understand how it works

Answer (score 2):

**Method one: Identify tool**

Select the Identify tool and click on the visible raster. Be sure the Identify tool mode is set to Top Down. The Identify window will pop up and give you information about all the layers where you clicked, including the raster layer.

**Method two: Map Tips**

Create a polygon layer with a polygon that covers the extent of each raster. Add the raster name as a text attribute. Display this layer as outlines only, or with no symbology if you don't want to see borders between the rasters. Put this layer at the top of the layer panel. Turn on Map Tips (Attributes toolbar > show map tips).

[image]

Now the "raster name" attribute value will appear when you hover the mouse over a raster extent polygon. You can adjust how long it takes for the map tip to appear in Settings menu > Options.

Comment: Good solutions, and the second one an alternative approach.